# vb.net - Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: vb.net

I got a problem in vb.net. By the way I am a newbie. I need your help
what's problem on this error:

My code:

```
Public Sub load_stockid_monthly_byUP(ByVal type As Integer, ByVal filter As Integer, ByVal input As String)
    Dim sqlquery As String = ""
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim where As String = ""
    Dim order As String = ""
    If filter = 1 Then
        where = ""
    ElseIf filter = 2 Then
        where = " AND r.type =" & input
    ElseIf filter = 3 Then
        where = " AND s.cat_id =" & input
    ElseIf filter = 4 Then
        where = " AND (s.desp like '% " & input & " %' OR s.desp like '" & input & " %' OR s.desp like '% " & input & "' OR s.desp = '" & input & "')"
    ElseIf filter = 5 Then
        where = " AND (s.cat_id = 1 OR s.cat_id = 2 OR s.cat_id = 4 OR s.cat_id = 5 )"
    ElseIf filter = 6 Then
        where = " AND (s.pallet_id <> 0 OR s.carton_id <> 0)"
        order = " ORDER BY  carton_id, pallet_id , stock_id"
    ElseIf filter = 7 Then
        where = " AND (s.pallet_id <> 0)"
        order = " ORDER BY pallet_id , stock_id"
    ElseIf filter = 8 Then
        where = " AND (s.carton_id <> 0)"
        order = " ORDER BY carton_id, stock_id"
    ElseIf filter = 9 Then
        where = " AND (s.uniform_id <> 0)"
        order = " ORDER BY uniform_id"
    End If


    If type = 1 Then
        sqlquery = "(SELECT s.id AS id,s.stock_id AS stock_id ,s.packing_id AS packing_id ,s.carton_id AS carton_id, s.pallet_id AS pallet_id, s.desp AS desp,i.unit_price AS unit_price, i.rate AS rate, c.type AS cat, u.unit AS uom, s.currency AS currency, s.uniform_id As uniform_id  FROM incoming AS i LEFT JOIN stock AS s ON i.stock_id = s.id LEFT JOIN uom AS u ON s.uom = u.id LEFT JOIN stock_cat AS c ON s.cat_id = c.id LEFT JOIN supplier AS r ON s.supplier_id = r.id WHERE s.active = 1 AND (i.active = 1 OR i.active = 2)" & where & " GROUP BY c.type, s.stock_id , i.unit_price, i.rate ) UNION " _
                    & "(SELECT s.id AS id,s.stock_id AS stock_id ,s.packing_id AS packing_id ,s.carton_id AS carton_id, s.pallet_id AS pallet_id,s.desp AS desp,i.unit_price AS unit_price, i.rate AS rate, c.type AS cat, u.unit AS uom, s.currency AS currency, s.uniform_id As uniform_id  FROM adjust AS i LEFT JOIN stock AS s ON i.stock_id = s.id LEFT JOIN uom AS u ON s.uom = u.id LEFT JOIN stock_cat AS c ON s.cat_id = c.id LEFT JOIN supplier AS r ON s.supplier_id = r.id WHERE s.active = 1 AND i.adjust_qty > 0 AND (i.active = 1 OR i.active = 2)" & where & " GROUP BY c.type, s.stock_id , i.unit_price, i.rate ) " & order
        ' sqlquery = "SELECT s.id AS id,s.stock_id AS stock_id ,s.desp AS desp,i.unit_price AS unit_price, i.rate AS rate, c.type AS cat, u.unit AS uom, s.currency AS currency FROM incoming AS i LEFT JOIN stock AS s ON i.stock_id = s.id LEFT JOIN uom AS u ON s.uom = u.id LEFT JOIN stock_cat AS c ON s.cat_id = c.id LEFT JOIN supplier AS r ON s.supplier_id = r.id WHERE (i.active = 1 OR i.active = 2)" & where & " GROUP BY c.type, s.stock_id , i.unit_price ORDER BY c.type ,s.stock_id "
    ElseIf type = 2 Then
        sqlquery = "SELECT s.id AS id,s.stock_id AS stock_id ,s.desp AS desp,n.unit_price AS unit_price, n.rate AS rate, c.type AS cat, u.unit AS uom, s.currency AS currency FROM issue AS i LEFT JOIN stock AS s ON i.stock_id = s.id  LEFT JOIN uom AS u ON s.uom = u.id LEFT JOIN incoming AS n ON i.irm_id = n.id LEFT JOIN stock_cat AS c ON s.cat_id = c.id LEFT JOIN supplier AS r ON s.supplier_id = r.id WHERE s.active = 1 AND i.active = 1" & where & " GROUP BY c.type, s.stock_id , n.unit_price ORDER BY c.type ,s.stock_id"
    End If


    stock_id_count = 0
    ConnectmyDB()
    myCommand.Connection = conn

    myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery
    myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader

    If myData.HasRows = False Then
        x = 1
    Else
        While myData.Read
            data(x, 0) = myData.GetInt32("id")
            data(x, 1) = myData.GetString("stock_id")
            data(x, 2) = myData.GetString("desp")
            data(x, 8) = myData.GetString("unit_price")

            data(x, 9) = myData.GetString ("rate")

            data(x, 12) = myData.GetString("cat")
            data(x, 14) = myData.GetString("uom")
            data(x, 16) = myData.GetString("packing_id")
            x = x + 1
        End While
    End If
    DisconnectDatabase()
    stock_id_count = x

End Sub 'closing stock unit price
```

I get the error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array for that code `'data(x, 0) = myData.GetInt32("id")'`

How to fix that?

This is what i get when run in program:

> ************** Exception Text **************
>   System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>      at Purchasing.mdlStoreBalance.load_stockid_monthly_byUP(Int32 type, Int32 filter, String input)
>      at Purchasing.frmStockBalanceReport.bt_preview_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Thank you

Comment: where did you defined the data array and whats is defenition?

Comment: Public data(20000, 20) As String
Public stock_id_temp(10000) As String
Public stock_id_count As Integer = 0
Public cur_month(10) As String
Public Sub clear_data_array()
        Array.Clear(data, 0, 400000)
        Array.Clear(stock_id_temp, 0, 10000)
End Sub

Comment: check the value of x when you get the error, is it >= 20000?

Comment: should i increase or decrease that numbers?

Comment: you define data array with `data(20000, 20) ` so first element has max 20000 items, if x becomes greater than it, you have to increase your array capacity. check the value of x when you get the error

Comment: can i know data(20000, 20)..20 is what?

Comment: yo define a 2 dimensional array, 20000 in first dim, and 20 in second dim. then you can use: data(0,0) , data(0,1), data(0,2), ... data(0,19),  then data(1,0), .... data(1,19), data(2,0)...data(2,19), .... .... data(19999,0) ... data(19999,19)

Comment: i have increase the number from 20000 to 30000..when i run in program it will loading.. loading and loading for a long time..why?n what should i do?

Comment: so you have many records in your database. do you know how many items are there? you may consider add more restricted where clause in your sql or use something like TOP 1000 to get only required amount of data

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: e.g: within your `While` loop, add this: `If x+1 >= 20000 Then Exit While`

Comment: i waiting for a long time..the result is error "conversion from string "Pcs" to type "Double" is not valid" at this line opening = FormatNumber(Cdbl(data(x, 4)) * Cdbl(data(x, 13)) * Cdbl(data(x, 14)), 2)

Answer (score 1):

Where is `data(x,?)` defined? You fill `data` within a `while` loop, but there is no checking to see if the `while` loop overruns the defined bounds.

I also can't tell how much data you expect to read. This will influence the run-time for the `while` loop and how high `x` is expected to get.

(would have asked this as a comment, but my rep is not yet high enough in this form).

As an aside, the checking of `filter` can be done in a `select case` statement. This will allow you to double check that you have covered `where` and `order` consistently. Also, as a coding convention, naming variables exactly the same as a one of your keywords (in this case a SQL keyword) can hide simple errors. Calling them something like `whereStmnt` and `orderStmnt` might help.

Comment: OK, comment above came in as I was typing. `data` is a public variable. but how much data is read?

Comment: what is this error meaning "conversion from string "Pcs" to type "Double" is not valid" at this line opening = FormatNumber(Cdbl(data(x, 4)) * Cdbl(data(x, 13)) * Cdbl(data(x, 14)), 2)

Comment: @Neqia: I can't see that line in the above code. Sounds like a new question.